# How to use as much as properly

Tags: conjunctions

I am confused which of these below sentences is correct.

1. you drink as much Milk as you wish.
2. you drink milk as much as you wish.

Comment: A lot of your questions have this structure  "Which sentence is correct?  1.... 2...."  These are not good questions.  They don't show any effort.  They don't explain why you think the sentence might be wrong.  They don't give the source or the context for the sentences.  Take a look at [ask] to see how to ask better questions.

Answer (score 1):

Both are possible.

> You drink as much milk as you wish.

This describes the amount of milk that you drink.

> You drink milk as much as you wish.

This is probably a badly expressed attempt to say "... as often as you wish". This describes when you drink milk.

In context it is unlikely to say "you do something".  You are more likely to say "I do something" or "Do you do something". Factual statements in the second person are rare.